# Return Object Instead of Array

Tags: php, oop

I really searched too much but i couldn't find anything. I'm newbie to classes that's why I'm getting trouble :)

My class is like below:

```
class Instagram
{
    public array $account = [];

    public function get_instagram_business_accounts(): array
    {
        return db()->query("SELECT followers_count FROM instagram_business_accounts ORDER BY username")->fetchAll();
    }

    public function get_followers_count()
    {
        return Miscellaneous::number_format($this->account["followers_count"]);
    }
}
```

I'm using the above class like this:

```
$accounts = new Instagram();
foreach($accounts->get_instagram_business_accounts() AS $account){
     $accounts->account = $account;
     echo $accounts->get_followers_count();
}
```

But I want to use like this:

```
$accounts = new Instagram();
foreach($accounts->get_instagram_business_accounts() AS $account){
     echo $account->get_followers_count();
}
```

I want to use `$account` as an object. How can I do this?

Best Regards,

=======
EDIT

I updated my main class like below:

```
class Instagram
{
    public function get_instagram_business_accounts(): array
    {
        $accounts = db()->query("SELECT followers_count FROM instagram_business_accounts ORDER BY username")->fetchAll();
        $return = [];
        foreach($accounts AS $account){
            $return[] = new InstagramAccount($account);
        }
        return $return;
    }
}
```

And my `InstagramAccount` class is below:

```
class InstagramAccount
{
    private int $followers_count;

    public function __construct(array $Instagram)
    {
        foreach($Instagram AS $key=>$value){
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }
    }

    public function get_followers_count(): string
    {
        return Miscellaneous::number_format($this->followers_count);
    }

}
```

Now I do what i want, right?

Comment: Ehm.. you already do?

Comment: My way is right?

Comment: Well... the indirection is correct (`$object->method()`)

Comment: Please edit your question only with the required snippets and driver code. This is super confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*get_followers_count()* is a method of class Instagram. In your second code you try to call this method from *$account* which is an array. That doesn't work

Comment: I think, i figured my problem out.. I'll update my question in few minutes..

Comment: Can you check my question? I added my solution, is it okay? And is this a good practise?

Comment: Yes,now it seems good